# Ricci curvature of the Grassmannian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, grassmannian

Let $G(k, \mathbb{C}^n)$ be the Grassmannian of $k-$dimensional complex linear subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n.$  We know that the Grassmannian can be embedded to the projective space $(\mathbb{P}^N,\omega_{FS})$ for some $N,$ via the Plucker embedding.

What can we say about the Ricci curvature of the Grassmannian? or even the scalar curvature? (any bounds?)

Comment: The Grassmanian is diffeomorphic to the homogeneous space $U(n)/U(n-k) \times U(k)$.  I believe the isotropy representation is irredicuble, and if true, this implies the Grassmanian has a unique homogeneous metric, up to rescaling.  So, the question then becomes:  is the induced metric on $G(k,\mathbb{C}^n)$ embedded into $\mathbb{P}^N$ homogeneous?  (I don't know enough about the Plucker embedding to answer the question).

Comment: @Joe: As with your question about the diameter, the answer depends on a choice of metric, including overall scaling. (As Jason DeVito notes, the Grassmannian admits a unique homogeneous Kähler metric, which is necessarily Einstein with positive Ricci curvature. The value of the Einstein constant, or of the scalar curvature, depends on the scaling.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Plücker embedding is an isometry of $G(k,\Bbb C^n)$ to its image in $\Bbb P(\Lambda^k\Bbb C^n)$ with the standard Fubini-Study metric.

In the moving frames notation, for example, the Kähler form on $\Bbb P^N$ is given by $$\frac i2\sum_{j=1}^N \omega_{0\bar j}\wedge\overline\omega_{0\bar j},$$
where $\{f_0;f_1,\dots,f_N\}$ is a unitary frame at the point $[e_0]\in\Bbb P^N$, and $\omega_{0\bar j} = \langle de_0,e_j\rangle$. (That is, $\omega_{0\bar j}$ give an invariant unitary basis for the $(1,0)$ cotangent bundle of $\Bbb P^N$.)

Now, using adapted unitary frames $\{e_\alpha;e_\mu\}$ ($\alpha=1,\dots,k$, $\mu=k+1,\dots,n$) on $G(k,\Bbb C^n)$, the Plücker embedding is given by the mapping $[e_1\wedge\dots\wedge e_k]$, so, taking $f_0=e_1\wedge\dots\wedge e_k$ and differentiating, we see that $$df_0 = \sum_{\alpha,\mu} \omega_{\alpha\bar\mu}e_1\wedge\dots\wedge e_\mu\wedge\dots\wedge e_k,$$ with $e_\mu$ in the $e_\alpha$ slot. That is, the $\omega_{\alpha\bar\mu}$ give the pullback of the unitary coframe on $\Bbb P^N$ ($N=\binom nk$). But they are also the invariant unitary coframe on the hermitian symmetric space $U(n)/\big(U(k)\times U(n-k)\big)$.

Answer (score 3):

There even exist explicit calculations of the sectional curvatures of the Grassmannian. Standard references dates back at least to the following in the 60s:

Wong, Yung-Chow. "Differential geometry of Grassmann manifolds." Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences 57, no. 3 (1967): 589-594.

Wong, Yung-Chow. "Sectional curvatures of Grassmann manifolds." Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences 60, no. 1 (1968): 75-79.